# Can’t correctly deploy Dash 1.4.0 to CentOS Apache server, webpage stays in uploading state, why?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, centos, plotly-dash

I create the following small app with Dash 1.4.0 and Flask 1.0.2, please find it below. I was able to deploy it to Centos Apache server, it starts but the only stuff I get is a loading page, in browser console I see that some components are absent, please see printscreen (I deleted ip of my server in the picture), what should I do to solve the issue? It works in my PC with no problems

Console in Chrome browser:
[image]

**WebApp Code:**

```py
from libs.initsetup import InitSetup
import libs.dbops as dbops
import os
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask import Flask

on_server = True

if not on_server:
    WORKDIR = ""
else:
    WORKDIR = "/var/www/mosregwebsite_dash_plot"


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
server = Flask(__name__)

dash_app = dash.Dash(__name__,  server=server)

dash_app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
dash_app.css.config.serve_locally = True

cache = Cache(dash_app.server, config={
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'filesystem',
    'CACHE_DIR': WORKDIR + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'cache-directory')
})

TIMEOUT = 1800  # plots are updated every 30 minutes


@cache.memoize(timeout=TIMEOUT)
def return_layout():
    clients = InitSetup.read_initfile_json(WORKDIR + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "jsons", "clients.json"))
    HOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, AUTH_PLUGIN, *rest = InitSetup.read_mysql_init_config_file(WORKDIR +
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "mosregwebsite_dash_plot.config.txt"))

    conn, curs = dbops.create_mysql_connection(HOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, AUTH_PLUGIN)

    graphs = []
    for k, v in clients.items():
        x, y = dbops.select_data_for_pictures(curs, k)
        graphs.append({'x': x, 'y': y, 'type': 'lineplot', 'name': v})

    return html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Graph(
            style={
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'height': '900px',
            },
            id='example-graph',
            figure={
                'data': graphs,
                'layout': {
                }

            }
        )
    ])


    dash_app.layout = return_layout

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        os.mkdir("numbeo")
        if not on_server:
            dash_app.run_server(host='127.0.0.107', port=8999, debug=False)
        else:
            HOST, PORT = InitSetup.read_website_settings_from_config_file(
                WORKDIR + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 
    "mosregwebsite_dash_plot.config.txt"))
        dash_app.run_server(host=HOST, port=int(PORT), debug=False)



    #########    WSGI FILE:   ##################

    import sys
    import os
    activate_this = '/var/www/mosregwebsite_dash_plot/env/bin/activate_this.py'
    with open(activate_this) as file_:
        exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
    sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/mosregwebsite_dash_plot/')


    from mosregwebsite_dash_plot import server as application

    #######    SETUP.PY    ##############


    from setuptools import setup


    setup(
        name='mosreg_webscrap_website',
        version='1.0.0',
        packages=[''],
        url='',
        license='',
        author='kozyrev.av',
        author_email='kozirev8@gmail.com',
        description='This is website which display processed information from 
    mosreg website',
       install_requires=[
            'dash==1.4.0',
            'Flask-Caching==1.7.2',
            'mysql-connector==2.2.9',
            'mysql-connector-python==8.0.16',
            'flask==1.0.2'
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am having the same issue!

Comment: @JorgeQuintana unfortunately I did not find solution, at the momemnt we're using flask with matplotlib to draw static plots, now we use ngnix and docker, soon start using green unicorn, later we'll implement plots with the help of vanilla js plot library like Google Charts.

Answer (score 1):

https://dash.plot.ly/react-for-python-developers check everything is installed correctly.

> To install Node.js, go to the Node.js website to download the latest
>   version. We recommend installing the LTS version.
>   Node.js will
>   automatically install the Node Package Manager npm on your machine
>   Verify that node is installed by running: node -v
>   Verify that npm is
>   installed by running: npm -v