# How do I deploy a Python Dash app locally without the desired users and the server having all associated dependencies installed?

Tags: python, deployment, server, wsgi, plotly-dash

Forgive me, I'm new to all this. It might not even be possible?

I have a Dash app that does a number of calculations, and I need to deploy it locally somehow.

I need all users in our company to be able to view it, but without the dependencies of the packages. I cannot use any web-based (Heroku, Git, etc) method as the data is commercially sensitive and must remain site-only.

I can successfully run it through waitress-serve on my machine and it can be viewed on other computers, but I'd rather it run from the server and be accessible by anyone that wants to use it.

What's the solution? Is is possible to have a folder on the server that has all the associated files and dependencies, and then a batch file (or similar - that's what I use now to launch mine) to launch the app on a wsgi server? Would our network have to have the python dependencies installed however?

Comment: I have the same problem (can't deploy to my own server) and no answer unfortunately https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343593/can-t-correctly-deploy-dash-1-4-0-to-centos-apache-server-webpage-stays-in-uplo

Comment: Appears no one knows, left it a while to see if I got anything back, but no joy. Good luck getting an answer for yours too.

Comment: Science Thank you! I wich I find the answer

Comment: Not really a direct answer to your question, but for demo's I've used [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/) before. So you would run the app on a certain port inside a terminal instance and in another terminal instance you could let ngrok create a secure public available url for the process running on localhost.